# Ad Overlaying Interface Instead Of Appearing Above It

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, overlay, admob

First I want to thank everyone here for their help on my previous questions. You've all been an immeasurable help. This will hopefully be my last question on this particular program and if it's been answered already then please link me to where as I couldn't find it via searching. What's going on now is that instead of the banner ad appearing and moving the rest of the interface down, it's appearing overlayed on top of my UI and blocking access to the part of the UI that is under it. Aside from that, everything is working great. Here's the XML and the JAVA.

Layout.XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/AdRelativeLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Ad Placeholder -->

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a15138b1a7adad2"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/BaseScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/baseVerticalLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutH1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/Sad" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/Happy" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/happinessBarID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="@integer/SliderMax"
            android:progress="@integer/SliderDefault" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutH2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/Tired" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/Awake" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/energyBarID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="@integer/SliderMax"
            android:progress="@integer/SliderDefault" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutH3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/Calm" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/Anxious" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/anxietyBarID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="@integer/SliderMax"
            android:progress="@integer/SliderDefault" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutH4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/No_Pain" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/Max_Pain" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/painBarID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="@integer/SliderMax"
            android:progress="@integer/SliderDefault" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/noteTextFieldID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/Note_Hint"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLength="@integer/NoteLimit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/enterButtonID"
            android:layout_width="132dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="dialogPop"
            android:text="@string/EnterButtonText" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the Java file...

```
package com.loch.meaptracker;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.ads.*;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private SeekBar happyBar, energyBar, anxietyBar, painBar;
private EditText noteField;
private DatePicker dPick;
private TimePicker tPick;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Button enterButton;
private int happyValue = 4, energyValue = 4, anxietyValue = 4,
        painValue = 4;
private static final String TAG = "heapApp";
private String Mood = "Blah";
private AdView adView;
final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView (this, AdSize.BANNER, "a15138b1a7adad2");

        // Lookup your RelativeLayout assuming it's been given the attribute android:id="@+id/AdRelativeLayout
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.AdRelativeLayout); 

        // Add the AdView to it
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        // bars
        happyBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.happinessBarID);
        happyBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        energyBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.energyBarID);
        energyBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        anxietyBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.anxietyBarID);
        anxietyBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        painBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.painBarID);
        painBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        // end bars
        dPick = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        tPick = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
        noteField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteTextFieldID);
        enterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterButtonID);
    } catch (Exception onCreateException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", onCreateException);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

// Bar listener methods
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int barValue, boolean hFromUser) {
    try {

        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.happinessBarID:
            happyValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.energyBarID:
            energyValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.anxietyBarID:
            anxietyValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        case R.id.painBarID:
            painValue = barValue + 1;
            break;
        }
        String debugBarValue = "Happy is " + happyValue + ", Energy is "
                + energyValue + ", Anxiety is " + anxietyValue
                + ", Pain is " + painValue + ".";
        System.out.println(debugBarValue);

    } catch (Exception BarValueException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", BarValueException);
    }

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar happyBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar happyBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

// end Bar listener methods

// Enter Button listener Method

public void dialogPop(View v) {
    try {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

        // set Title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("You entered: " + getMood())
                .setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Okay",
                // When Okay button clicked the write mood string to file
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                try {
                                    // This is the string that should be
                                    // written to file
                                    String data = getMood();
                                    // This is the file that should be
                                    // written to
                                    File heapFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "heapFile.csv");

                                    // if file doesn't exists, then create
                                    // it
                                    if (!heapFile.exists()) {
                                        heapFile.createNewFile();
                                    }

                                    // true = append file
                                    FileWriter heapFileWritter = new FileWriter(
                                            heapFile.getName(), true);
                                    BufferedWriter heapBufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(
                                            heapFileWritter);
                                    heapBufferWritter.write(data);
                                    heapBufferWritter.close();

                                    System.out.println("Done");

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        })
                // If they press either the cancel button or the back button
                // on their device (Same thing) then close the dialog and
                // give the user a chance to change what they've entered
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception buttonListenerException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", buttonListenerException);
    }
    return;
}

public String getMood() {
    try {
        int month = dPick.getMonth();
        int day = dPick.getDayOfMonth();
        int year = dPick.getYear();
        int minute = tPick.getCurrentMinute();
        String moodAntePost = "AM";
        boolean hourType = tPick.is24HourView();
        int moodHour = tPick.getCurrentHour();
        if (hourType == false && moodHour > 12) {
            moodHour = (moodHour - 12);
            moodAntePost = "PM";
        } else if (hourType == false && moodHour <= 0) {
            moodHour = 12;
        } else {
        }
        String noteText = noteField.getText().toString();
        Mood = "Happiness," + happyValue + ",Energy," + energyValue
                + ",Anxiety," + anxietyValue + ",Pain," + painValue
                + ",Date," + month + "/" + day + "/" + year + ",Time,"
                + moodHour + ":" + minute + "," + moodAntePost + ",Note,"
                + noteText;
        System.out.println(Mood);
    } catch (Exception getMoodException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception received", getMoodException);
    }

    return Mood;
}

}
```

Comment: Use a linearlayout instead of the relative layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can both choose to substitute the outer RelativeLayout with a LinearLayout or placing a `android:layout_below="@id/adView"` in your Scrollview.

By the way, your inner layout looks deeply nested. You should consider replacing it with a relativelayout or a gridlayout for better performances.